# QT Android Gstreamer RTMP stream pipe green line glitch

Tags: android, qt, stream, gstreamer, rtsp

System used:
QT - 5.14
Gstreamer - 1.18
Android - ndk 21, BULD SDK 30

I have following pipe line for QT application which stream video to server from local rtsp source.

```
QString cmdStream = "rtspsrc location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/fpv_stream latency=200 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! video/x-h264 ! queue  ! flvmux name=mux streamable=true ! rtmpsink sync=true async=true location=\""+urlStream+" live=1\"";
```

This pipe line **works good** for HD video (1280x720). But getting **problem for Full** HD(1920x1080) resolution.

Working with HD:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2R8u.jpg)

Not workingwith FHD:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnhy6.jpg)

What will be the problem as same pipe works for HD video and not work for FHD? I have tried with modify ***sync,latency add queue*** to some elements

Answer (score 1):

Got this working with following pipe line

```
cmdStream = "rtspsrc location=\"rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/fpv_stream\" name=rtspscr1 ! capsfilter caps=\"application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, payload=(int)96, encoding-name=(string)H264, a-framerate=(string)24.000000\" ! queue ! rtph264depay ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream ! h264parse !  queue ! flvmux ! rtmpsink sync=true async=true location=\""+urlStream+"\"";
```

This pipe line works due to changes in  **video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream** this elements handles stream very well that works with HD and FHD stream.